# How can I know if another Mac app has delayed idle sleep?

Tags: objective-c, macos, iokit

I have a non-sandboxed OS X app which needs to know if any other app is delaying idle sleep (through use of `IOPMAssertionCreateWithName()` and/or `IOCancelPowerChange`).

I don't need to know why, I just need to know that they're delaying it for some reason, which would mean my app should wait before trying to lock the screen because the user is currently using the system (to watch video, for example).

Is there a way of knowing that idle sleep has been temporarily delayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use `IOPMCopyAssertionsStatus()` for this. That will output a dictionary indicating the system-wide assertion level for the various assertions. Look up the value for `kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleDisplaySleep` (or `kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleSystemSleep` if that's what you really want). If it's present and greater than 0, something is preventing idle display/system sleep.

Comment: Precisely what I needed. MAY I KISS YOU, KEN?